# Play Store is not publishing my app on play store with BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN, DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED and DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED, permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, publish, android-permissions

I am **adding some Admin permission** in manifest. after 2 days wait its not publishing app on play store with this permissions. I listed below that permissions

- BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN
- DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED
- DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED

Now, while i am trying to publish that app in **play store** at that time app  successful upload but it's not publishing. It's every time show **"Pending publication"**. And **while i remove this permission** it's **published Successful**.

So, any one can tell me that what is the **reason** behind this issue. **Why play store not publishing my app with that permission?**

Comment: Pending publication means, your app is currently progressing for publishing, it will take 2-3 hours to be available in play store

Comment: ya but after 2 days its displaying same message. Not publishing and not giving any error or report.

Comment: check whether you have uploaded app as test version or so.

Comment: i just remove these permissions and it published successful. i did not make other change.

Comment: How did you implement device administrator beyond defining it in the Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Read through the Deceptive Device Settings Changes policy for more details, and make sure your app complies with all policies listed in the Developer Program Policies.

If you don't need the BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission in your app:
Remove your request for this permission from your app's manifest.
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the modified, policy compliant APK.
Or, 
if you need the BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission in your app:
Include the following snippet in your app’s store listing description: 
**“This app uses the Device Administrator permission.”**
Provide prominent user facing disclosure of this usage before asking the user to enable this permission within your app. Your disclosure must meet each of the following requirements:
Disclosure must be displayed in normal course of usage of your app. Your users should not be required to navigate into a menu or settings to view disclosure.
Disclosure must describe the functionality Device Admin permission is enabling for your app. Each security policy used with the Device Admin request must be declared in your disclosure, and each policy must be accompanied with justification for the request.
Disclosure cannot only be placed in your privacy policy, terms of service or end user license agreement (EULA).
If approved, your app will again be available with all installs, ratings, and reviews intact.

Answer (score -1):

**Publishing status**
(https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/xkxQuf-oDck)

Near the top of individual apps’ pages on your Developer Console, you can see your app’s latest publishing status. Whether you’re publishing an app for the first time or making an update, you can use your publishing status to understand your app’s availability on Google Play.

Here are the different statuses that can be displayed for your app:

**Draft:** App hasn’t been published on Google Play.
Note: If the Publish app option isn’t available, click Why can’t I publish? for more information or check your app’s pages on the left menu to make sure you’ve included all required information for your app.

**Pending publication:** App is currently being processed for publishing.

**Published:** App is published and available on Google Play.

**Rejected:** App has been rejected and wasn’t published due to a violation of Google Play policies. More information about the violation is available near the top of your app’s pages on the Developer Console. Once you make a change to your app to address the violation, you can submit it again.

**Suspended:** App is suspended due to a violation of Google Play Policies (Content Policy, Developer Distribution Agreement). An email with details about the suspension is sent to the account owner.

Comment: i published near about 15 apps sir. i know everything but no one app take 2 or 3 days to publish app. at the end its not published. it still in "Pending publication".

Comment: check this one https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

Comment: i  am Account owner and sorry to say but actually you did not get what issue i m facing. can you please read my question twice.

Comment: sorry I dont know, 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#manifest says something about ur need